# How to find maximum from given function with given range in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have implemented functions find_maximum and f, that returns the value and passed it as a parameter to another function and just wanted to find the maximum of the given function. Following is my implementation.

```
import numpy as np
def find_maximum(f, begin_range, end_range, step=0.00001):
    return np.maximum(begin_range, np.minimum(f, end_range))

def f(x):
    myList = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        myList.append(0.3333* x**2) - 5*x - 3 + (numpy.cos(3)*x) 
    return myList

x = 4
print(find_maximum(f, -4, 4, 0.00001))
```

*Following is more explanation*

f - A vectorized python function of a single variable f(x), that expects
a numpy array of x values as its only parameter.
begin_range, end_range - real valued numbers with begin_range < end_range,
defining a range that we want to determine the maximum value of the
given function within.
step - The step size to search within the range, defaults to 0.001 The
maximum will be determined to a value within this step size, so it
represents the accuracy with which to find the maximum.

Returns max_loc - returns the location where the function is at the maximum in
the given range. The location of the maximum must be within the range:
begin_range <= max_loc <= end_range

**An Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b68bd5d55098> in <module>()
     29     return myList
     30 x = 4
---> 31 print(find_maximum(f, -4, 4, 0.00001))

<ipython-input-6-b68bd5d55098> in find_maximum(f, begin_range, end_range, step)
      1 import numpy as np
      2 def find_maximum(f, begin_range, end_range, step=0.00001):
----> 3     return np.maximum(begin_range, np.minimum(f, end_range))
      4 '''Find the maximum of function f in the range [begin_range, end_range].
      5 The function f should be a vectorized python function of a single

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
```

**Expected output**

```
print(find_maximum(f, -4, 4, 0.00001))
>>> -2.14085
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```py
x = 4
print(find_maximum(f(x), -4, 4, 0.00001))
```

You need to run your function before give it to find_maximum

Edit :

You function miss a parenthesis :

```py
def f(x):
    myList = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        myList.append((0.3333* x**2) - 5*x - 3 + (np.cos(3)*x)) 
    return myList
```

Comment: @MayurPotdar Look at my update anwser and check that the formula is stiil valide.

Comment: Thanks and I figured it out. I'm getting `NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`  Error. However, I have imported numpy.

Comment: @MayurPotdar my bad, I have update my anwser again, this function should work. Numpy do not exist in the namespace as we have import it as np